# Error when creating an ELB in AWS using boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-ec2

How do I get a list of security groups in a non default VPC? 
I create a VPC and then create security groups in it. Later in the code I need to find a security group by name, so I do a describe_security_groups() call, but I am getting this error, as the code is only listing security groups in the default VPC.

```
EXCEPTION An error occurred (InvalidGroup.NotFound) when calling the DescribeSecurityGroups operation: The security group 'elb_security_group' does not exist in default VPC 'vpc-4e39c02b'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get a list of the security groups available in a given VPC using the [security_groups](http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Vpc.security_groups) collection

```
    import boto3

    ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
    vpc = ec2.Vpc('id')
    security_group_iterator = vpc.security_groups.all()
```

Comment: Its a different way of accessing the same info, but yes, this will work for now.